# Is there a difference between a MDI Client, a MDI Container, and a MDI Parent?

Tags: c#, forms, mdi, mdichild, mdiparent

As it says, is there any difference between a MDI Client, Parent, or Container?

If they are all the same. Does this mean that all MDI applications cannot be more than 1 nested window deep?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have only one MDI parent form, as Microsoft says:

> The Microsoft Windows implementation of the multiple document interface (MDI) does not support nested MDI client windows. In other words, neither an MDI client window nor an MDI child window can have an MDI client window as a child.

About the terms, in the literature the most common words used are MDI Parent and MDI Child. Since the technology itself is just *MDI*, you are using *Parent* for the container and *Child* for the inside forms.

Comment: Is this a link to that quote? http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;74041

Comment: @user1596244 Yes it is. And I don't know what are you trying to do, but I suggest to reconsider trying to nest multiple forms. It does not seems to be a nice way...at all..